# Log-Normalization of skewed data before feeding to neural network models ( autoencoders)

Tags: outliers, normalization, skewness, autoencoders, logarithm

If your input data has few columns that are extremely skewed, It is well known that one would log normalize ( take log and then normalize or standardize) the data before passing to regression techniques.

Would the same be advisable while using deep learning networks (more specifically auto-encoders for outlier detection)

Another variation being - does it make sense to give both the original variable and the log normalized variable to multivariate autoencoders?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure about all the questions, but log-normalization will not work with data that is negative or zero. 
I routinely use sklearn's PowerTransformer to scale features that suffer from high skewness (usually due to outliers) which usually leads to slight performance improvements of my NN models. But it seems a bit odd to me to use a scaling method that usually suppress outliers in order to detect outliers.